# Trouble Sorting a 2d struct Array in C

Tags: c

I have a (150x150)2d array of structs that i'd like to sort in a row independent fashion. Because it is a struct, i do not believe (correct me if i'm wrong here) i cannot use qsort() or at least do not know how to due to the fact i'm paring structs and the element i am comparing is a double which goes against the compare prototype requirement of qsort(). At any rate i'd like to apply quicksort on

```
  struct my_struct {
    int x;
    int y;
    double d;
 };
void quicksort(struct my_struct* array,int start, int end)
{

struct my_struct key, Pivot;
int i,j,PivotPoint;
if(start< end)
{
    PivotPoint = (start+end)/2;
    theswap(&array[start], &array[PivotPoint]);
    key = array[start];
    i= start+1;
    j = end;
    while (i<=j)
    {
        while((i<=end) && (array[i].d <= key.d))
            ++i;
        while ((j>=start) && array[j].d> key.d) {
            --j;
            if (i<j) {
                theswap(&array[i], &array[j]);
            }
        }
    }
    theswap(&array[start], &array[j]);
    quicksort(array, start, j-1);
    quicksort(array, j+1, end);
    }
}
void theswap(struct my_struct *a, struct TourElement *b)
{
struct my_struct t;
t=*a; 
*a=*b;
*b=t;
}
```

in my main function
i have something
like this:

```
 for (i=0;i<150;++i)
   {
   for (j=0;j<150;++j)
   { 
    My_array[i][j].x = somethingUseful;
    My_Array[i][j].y = somethingEquallyUseful;
    My_Array[i][j].d = CalcD(somethingUseful,somethingEquallyUseful);
    }
    qsort(My_Array[i],150,sizeof(my_struct),compare);
   }


       int compare(struct my_struct a , struct my_struct b)
     {
          return a.d -b.d;
     }
```

When i execute quicksort, the application hangs, upon further investigation, there doesn't seem to be any elements in array within the quicksort function. (I added a for loop printf at the beginning of quicksort to itemize the struct's d values and nothing was printed)

Can anyone identify what i am doing wrong here?  I'm getting no compile errors.  And The "D"s are calculated correctly.

Comment: Vote to close: Asking strangers to spot errors in your code by inspection is not productive.  You should identify (or at least isolate) the problem by using a debugger or print statements, and then come back with a more specific question.  Incidentally, you *can* use `qsort` on arbitrary structs, there are lots of examples out there.

Comment: You can use [`qsort()`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#7.20.5.2) (which doesn't necessarily apply the "quick sort" algorithm) with arrays of structs. For ease-of-use just pretend your two-dimensional array is uni-dimensional.

Comment: OI tried to use qsort() but it didn't actually sort.  but at least it didn't hang. Going to edit code above.

Comment: I should note, that this is just a piece of a MPI program and honestly, do not know how to debug this with a debugger and as i mentionned earlier the prints didn't actually print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use std c qsort

```
void qsort( void *buf, size_t num, size_t size, int (*compare)(const void *, const void *) );
```

the compare function is something like this:

```
int my_struct_comp(const void *p1, const void *p2){
  my_struct *mp1 = (my_Struct*)p1;
  my_struct *mp2 = (my_Struct*)p2;

  return mp1->d - mp2->d;
}
```

than you can call qsort (where len is the length of the array)

```
qsort(myarray, len, sizeof(my_struct), &my_struct_cmp);
```

Comment: Yes! thank you.  My initial attempt din't have the & therefore not working.  Kudos!